# How to get access token for Huawei Api for sending push to device?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I need to send push to Huawei device, which have app with Huawei Push Kit integrated. To do this I need accessToken. How to receive it? I've already create developer account and create project for app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You need to do POST request to `https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token`
2. Add header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Add params:

   - `grant_type=client_credentials`
   - `client_id=CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE`
   - `client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE`

Request using curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE'
```

`CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE` and `CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE` can be found in console so: `App Gallery Connect -> My projects -> YOUR_PROJECT -> Project settings`. On this screen `CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE` is `Application ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE` is `App secret`, which can be found near `SHA-256` of you signing keys.

[image]

---

To send push using accessToken see this question: [How to send push to Huawei device using Huawei Push Kit API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359941/)

---

You can find more information in documentation: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/open-platform-oauth-0000001053629189-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001063738301__section12493191334711

Comment: Access Token expires in 60 minutes, how to make it expire longer or permanently?

Comment: @KucingMalaya, as I know - there is no way to setup expiration time