# How to send push to Huawei device using Huawei Push Kit API?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I want to send push from server to Huawei device with Huawei Push Kit integrated. I have `deviceToken` from device, but when I try so send push message using API I receive error:

> 80300002: No permission to send message to these tmIDs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error can be caused be wrong `AppId`, used in API url path.

`AppId` can be found in console so: `App Gallery Connect -> My projects -> YOUR_PROJECT -> Project settings`. On this screen `AppId` is `Application ID`, which can be found above `SHA-256` of your signing keys.

[image]

So, working request using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) looks like (for notification push (shown in notification bar)):

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/APP_ID_FROM_CONSOLE/messages:send' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "Hello!",
            "body": "Hello, shirley!",
            "click_action": {
                "type": 3
            }
        },
        "android": {
            "urgency": "NORMAL",
            "ttl": "10000s",
            "notification": {
                "title": "Hello!",
                "body": "Hello, shirley!",
                "click_action": {
                    "type": 3
                }
            }
        },
        "token": [
            "DEVICE_TOKEN"
        ]
    }
}'
```

To get `ACCESS_TOKEN` see this question: [How to get access token for Huawei Api for sending push to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359394)

---

You can find more information in documentation:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001070412173__section134322259125

Comment: why it needs 2 'notification' in the body

Comment: @Choy, I don't know) As I remember, without 2 notifications parts it won't work