# Can't send notification [error: 80300002] (HMS Core Push Kit) - Web App

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have a **web app** project that sends out push notifications to phone browsers. I have successfully retrieved push token from my **Huawei device** but couldn't send notification through HMS Push Kit from my server, got an HTTP 401 and the error body contained:

```
{ 
  "msg": "No permission to send message to these tmIDs", 
  "code": 80300002
}
```

I've contacted the customer service and was pointed to the following URL, I did everything listed there but still get the same error.

> https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/commonerror-0000001059816656-V5

This is the URL (POST) that returned the error (sent from my server, using app ID from project settings):

> https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/my_app_id_from_project_settings/topic:subscribe

Access token was retrieved from the following URL using OAuth 2.0 Client ID/Secret from the console ("Credentials"):

> https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token

I've also applied for HUAWEI ID from the console (App Services > Development > HUAWEI ID, using the same OAuth 2.0 Client ID/secret).

What I did for troubleshoot:

- Push Kit Enabled (both **Console** level and **Project** level)
- Access token with backslash (\) removed and URL-encoded
- Server Location: **Singapore** (Push Kit disabled and re-enabled as advised)
- POST request body with a JSON body with only 2 properties `topic` (string) and `tokenArray` (string array, e.g. `["token1", "token2"]`)
- POST request headers with `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`
- POST request headers with `Content-Type: application/json`
- Debug using "Cloud Debugging" feature.
- Tested on emulator running Android 11 (API-level 30, HMS Core 5.0.3.304)
- Tested on my Huawei device running EMUI 8.0 (with Google Play Services)
- Tested on Android Chrome 87 (device), Android Chrome 83 (emulator)

Comment: Could you plz provide your appid? :)

Comment: Yes @shirley 9105385871711569431 :)

Comment: Check this, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359941/how-to-send-push-to-huawei-device-using-huawei-push-kit-api

Comment: @mohax I already did, I've read pretty much every post that I could find on StackOverflow regarding this issue before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create an Android application under the project of the web application, and obtain the **access_token** with the appid and appsecret of the Android app. Then the **access_token** can be passed into the send interface.

Comment: It finally worked, thanks! I will try to send notifications and see if my phone can receive any.

Comment: Hi @shirley, messages were sent out using the access_token (retrieved using android app ID and app secret) but no notification handlers were called in the client i.e. setBackgroundMessageHandler() and onMessage(), what should I do?

Comment: Hi @JesseS, could you please provide your **requestid token** and **appid of your Android app**?

Comment: Yes @shirley 
**App ID** (103600381) 
**Project ID** (736430079244754323)
** Access token (CgB6e3x99n5qf+W/BdFLSMnc+qCxAMoGO3aA9HM9aCjNx2aCmD+RtD+HRXMt8lc4pu9iLIeKUqEySt3qg4IWIdwO) 
** POST URL (https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/736430079244754323/messages:send)

Comment: @JesseS How about **requestid**?

Comment: From the response I got, requestId **160975077620556473000406**, code **80000000**, msg **Success**

Comment: @JesseS Yes, it is :) requestId is id returned by the push interface push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/736430079244754323/messages:send.

Comment: Oh oh I see. :)

Comment: @JesseS By the way, plz let me know where is your Data storage location? :)

Comment: Yes @shirley it is set to **Singapore**

Comment: @JesseS Plz try to pass the appid in the interface to send the messages, and see if it works. :)

Comment: Hi @shirley I tried passing in AppID as advised but now I get **80200001** **Authentication Error**, any ideas why? The client is initialized with Web app's API key, project ID and App ID.

Here: https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/9105385871711569431/messages:send

Comment: I've also tried to use Android App ID, API key in the client, but I still get **80200001 Authentication Error**

Comment: @JesseS Error 80200001 is related to the access token. The access token in the Authorization parameter in the request HTTP header failed to be authenticated. Ensure that the access token is correct. Plz obtain the latest access token.

Comment: Yes it's a fresh new access token @shirley

Raw: **CgB6e3x9oJb2p99EUC0UqIMsHT6YBJWqY1as2VEtCo3aQrH4tGjXkcE0gHmHd3lwUHrILrmXI55xCNl9I/6c9X+h**

Processed (encoded): **CgB6e3x9oJb2p99EUC0UqIMsHT6YBJWqY1as2VEtCo3aQrH4tGjXkcE0gHmHd3lwUHrILrmXI55xCNl9I/6c9X+h**


WeChat: js-mao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226912/discussion-between-jesse-s-and-shirley).