# How to use the device token to send downlink message

Tags: android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

After checking the official document, the device_token can not be used for hms_server to send downlink message. If i want to access hms_server, i must request another oauth2 token. Is it mean both the device_token and hms_server_token should be updated all the time, or choice only one like device_token to send downlink message?

```
URL: https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/appid/messages:send

Request Header: 
Authorization Bear token (need to request from hms_server, the device_token is only used for identify the address of device)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access token for Huawei Api for sending push to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359394/how-to-get-access-token-for-huawei-api-for-sending-push-to-device)

Comment: And this is how to send message to device, using token from previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359941/how-to-send-push-to-huawei-device-using-huawei-push-kit-api

Comment: Why not use the device_token to replace the server_oauth_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `device_token` and `access_token` are required. The `device_token` is obtained by the client and updated when the token changes. Changed scenario pls refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041).

The `access_token` has a validity period. When the `access_token` is obtained, the validity period is returned. Generally, the validity period is one hour. The `access_token` is used within the validity period and does not need to be updated each time.

Comment: If the access_token is outdated, can i use the previous token automatically to generate the new token and send the push message?

Comment: No you can't. If the `access_token` is outdated, you need to use the API to obtain it again.